# Disable Task Manager using c# from Limited User Account

Tags: c#

I need to disable and enable the taskmanager from my application.
I am doing this for my Kiosk application. I know i can do this
by changing the Key in registry using below code. But the problem
is my kiosk application will run in limited user account which does
not allow the application to change key in registry level.

Code working perfectly in Administrator account :

```
    RegistryKey regkey;
        string keyValueInt = "1";
        string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
        regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey);
        regkey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", keyValueInt);
        regkey.Close();
```

How can i achieve this in Limited user account ?

Comment: Please don't repost questions.  If you have more to add, edit your existing question.  [Disabling Task manager using c# in OS Hardened machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986782/disabling-task-manager-using-c-in-os-hardened-machine)

Comment: I think this question is totally different from my older post. I agree that it is about Task Manager. But the reason for this question is different. Its about User account and not OS Hardening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code requires an elevated privilege to access registry. However there is just a fragment of code that requires these extra permission. To handle such scenarios impersonation is used i.e. you will execute this application as normal user only but that particular piece of code will be executed as if you were an Administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Open Notepad, copy and paste the code below, save as `Disable.reg` and run (double-click the file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableTaskMgr"=dword:1
```

Comment: Importing this into the registry would require administrative rights, which the original question specifically states will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

During the deployment of your application to the target machine you presumably have administrative access at some point, yes?  If so, know that registry keys are Win32 securable objects.

Log in as an administrator, right-click a registry key, choose "Permissions", and give read/write/etc. access rights to the user account in which your application will run.  Click on the advanced button and make sure to give the same permissions to all subkeys since you're creating keys with your application.

To automate deployment of your application, these steps can be done programmatically from an administrator user account using the .NET framework's wrappers on the Win32 security API's.

Obviously, this solution creates a security hole.  You're giving that user account access rights that, as far as I know, may be exploited to gain root access.  Without a deep investigation of the side-effects of task manager, you can't be sure of the scope of the hole.  Since you're talking about a kiosk app, it seems likely that this won't be a problem for you, but I just wanted to make sure you know the consequences of your actions.

If you want a truly secure App, you'd need to create a service that runs in an administrative account and have it implement an API that provides just the functionality of the task manager that you really need rather than exposing the whole thing and expose the API through pipes or shared memory, or some other inter-process communication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

For kiosk applications, I would generally create a restrictive group policy that gets applied upon startup.  With the [group policy editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882), you can disallow the user from accessing the start bar, the task manager, ctrl alt delete, Alt-Tab, Alt-F4 etc.  If you can't get this kind of access to the OS, your kiosk app is going to have issues.